# Javascript placement in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

When building a standard (non-WordPress) web page, I generally load all javascript files just before the end of the body, and then include a section for page-specific js code.

WorPress recommends using the wp_enqueue_script() function for loading javascript, which allows for the option of loading scripts in either the header or footer.

Since WordPress headers and footers are encapsulated in their own files, where would one put code specific to a page-template?  It seems if you are using any non-site-wide scripts, you're forced to load your site-wide scripts in the header, and then insert the page-specific code somewhere else arbitrarily in the body, before the footer.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?  Am I thinking about this too much?

Comment: you can attach ondomready or onload events to your JavaScript, and then attach `<script>` tag in the `<head>` so you are insured that they'll be loaded after the dom is ready or the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Is_a_Page_Template) in header and load page template specific scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Add the javascript using a function and load it only when the given page template is attached.

**For example:**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'template_specific_scripts', 100 );

function template_specific_scripts() {
    if( is_page_template( 'some-page-template-filename.php' ) ) {
        // Using stylesheet_directory accounts for child themes
        $js_path = get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory') . '/yourfile.js'
        wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script-handle', $js_path );
    }
}
```

- `is_page_template()`

  - [Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)
- `wp_enqueue_script()`

  - [Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)
- `get_blogingo()`

  - [Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)

If you have any further WordPress related questions please consider posting them to the [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Hope that helps.